# H2 duplicate rows

Tags: duplicates, h2

I have a database with records and I would like to get rid of duplicates but in doing so I want to keep specific row.

When I find duplicate rows based on one column I would like to choose the one that have max date (the most fresh entry) but I want to keep all columns from that specific row.

Sample of data, see duplicate of Product B
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z24F0.jpg)

Expected result of query should be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g8G9.jpg)

I have the problem with keeping all column after group by.

My query is

SELECT "Product", max("Date") FROM #table#
GROUP BY "Product"

As a result I get Product and Date - and it is good but how can I get all other information from this row it means ID, Customer and other columns if database has it?

I have tried query
SELECT "Product", max("Date") FROM #table#
GROUP BY "Product"

In sqlite we have query
SELECT *, FROM #table#
GROUP BY "Product" HAVING MAX ("Date") and it does what I want so it keeps whole specific row with all enrties of all columns

how can I do it in H2?

Answer (score 0):

In H2 the simplest and fastest solution is PostgreSQL-style `DISTINCT ON` clause:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(PRODUCT VARCHAR, ID VARCHAR, DATE DATE, CUSTOMER VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
('A', 'X123', DATE '2023-06-06', 'C1'),
('B', 'Y234', DATE '2023-03-05', 'C8'),
('C', 'U345', DATE '2023-02-25', 'C9'),
('B', 'Y432', DATE '2023-06-01', 'C89'),
('D', 'Z852', DATE '2023-01-01', 'C4'),
('B', 'V324', DATE '2023-05-01', 'C8');

SELECT DISTINCT ON (PRODUCT) * FROM TEST ORDER BY PRODUCT, DATE DESC;
```

| PRODUCT | ID | DATE | CUSTOMER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X123 | 2023-06-06 | C1 |
| B | Y432 | 2023-06-01 | C89 |
| C | U345 | 2023-02-25 | C9 |
| D | Z852 | 2023-01-01 | C4 |